# Run Prolog code through Vim editor

Tags: vim, prolog

I have installed SWI-Prolog and an editor. I am currently writing and running the code using them. Lately I started working using the Vim editor, so I would like to ask, how can I run the Prolog code from Vim? Obviously I don't ask how can Vim run the code because it is just an editor not an IDE, I am asking how can I do it like when you run C or Python code from Vim.

Answer (score 2):

Running Prolog code from Vim requires loading your Prolog program and a Prolog query to execute using that program. For example, if your query is a call to the predicate `main/0`, then you could add to your `~/.vimrc` file something like:

```
map <F5> <ESC>:w<CR>:exec '!swipl -g "consult(''%''), main, halt"'<CR>
```

This, with your Prolog program in the current Vim buffer, pressing the function key `F5` would save it to disk, consult it with SWI-Prolog, call the goal `main`, and terminate the Prolog section (due to the call to the `halt/0` predicate).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but as I am not really experienced using Vim can you maybe be a little more specific?

Comment: Just edit your `~/.vimrc` file (create it if it doesn't exist already) and add to it the line above.

Comment: A more standard way to “run the current code” is setting the [`'makeprg'` option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27) so that [`:make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:make) runs the code. For example, have the line `set make=swipl\ -g\ \"consult(''%''),\ main,\ halt\"` in your `~/.vimrc` ([properly backslash-escaped](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#option-backslash)), and then type `:make` to run your Prolog code.